# What's the Best Way to Open a TCP Stream to Server?

Tags: ajax, tcp, streaming, client-server

Rather a hard to nail down question, but basically I'm wondering what the best way (and not "what's your opinion" but "which will most adequately meet the requirement i shall set forth) is to open a stream connection from a client side webpage to a server such that either can send data to the other without polling? I'm thinking the term for this is HTTP binding vs. HTTP Polling. The context here is a chat application - i'd like a streamed connection so that the browser isn't constantly pushing requests out.  The client end here is KnockoutJS and jQuery. I'd like to be able to have the data pushed back and forth be JSON (or at least manipulatable by jQuery and Knockout's `toJSON`).  The server end - not quite sure what it is going to be, but i'll probably be running on a linux server, so anything compatible with that works fine. 
If there's any more details i can provide, just let me know - i'm sure i left some obvious detail out. Also, i'm aware there's probably a duplicate question on this, so if your answer is as good as closing for a dupe and putting in a link, that's great. 
Thanks!

Comment: google and search SO for "comet", "reverse ajax", "long polling". And see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is referred to as Comet. The basic idea is to keep HTTP requests open for longer periods of time so that the server can send data to the client as it comes in, rather than the client having to continually poll the server for new data. There are multiple ways to implement it. This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) is a good start for more info.

This [MIX 2011 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/HTM10) discusses the long polling technique (although the suggestion in the video is that web sockets will be a better solution with future browsers).

Comment: Looks like AJAX Long Polling is what i want... am i correct in saying that it'd be as simple as a jQuery `$.ajax` request that's just held open on the server end and reopened as soon as the client gets it back?

Comment: @Thomas: afaiu it's not that simple. Long polling / comet is essentially an http hack. You'll need a server set up to handle connections that are left open, and I'm pretty sure you'll need some special js client-side. Comet is fiddly and not straightforward to set up. 99.9% you're better off just making regular ajax requests for new data. Almost all web-based chat clients work like this.

Comment: @Richard hm, okay. I just don't like firing off AJAX request after AJAX request unnecessarily.

Comment: @Thomas - sure but this is almost certainly better than trying to get HTTP to do something it's not designed to.

Comment: @Richard - good point. Would Web-Sockets be the way to go, then? (feel free to put your reply in a new answer)

Comment: @Thomas - yes definitely, but of course you only have bleeding edge browser support at the moment. So ideally you'll need to include graceful degradation to standard ajax polling.

Comment: @Richard i kinda figured. I'm thinking we'll be targeting IE10+ anyways, so no big deal. thanks a bunch!